# AWS Redshift: How to describe a library created in redshift?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am using python udfs. These udfs using certain python libraries. I have stored the wheels of these libraries in s3. I create those functions to be used from these libraries, so I've created library in redshift using the syntax:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] LIBRARY library_name LANGUAGE plpythonu
FROM
{ 'https://file_url'
| 's3://bucketname/file_name'
authorization
  [ REGION [AS] 'aws_region']
}
```

Can please help on how can I describe the definitions of this library incase if I have to validate if the wheel is the latest one or not?

Answer (score 2):

From [PG_LIBRARY - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_LIBRARY.html):

> Stores information about user-defined libraries

```
select * from pg_library;

name       | language_oid | file_store_id | owner
-----------+--------------+---------------+------
f_urlparse |       108254 |          2000 |   100
```

Comment: It just specifies the name of the library. Quest is to find the exact definition of this library. for example. what package it is pointing to and location etc.